# htaccess redirect subdomain to new domain WITHOUT subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Almost there:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forums\.resistance\.tk  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.libertaire.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect

http://forums.resistance.tk/message.php?t=7751

to

https://www.libertaire.net/forums/message.php?t=7758

but I want

https://www.libertaire.net/message.php?t=7758

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove `/forums/` while redirecting use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forums\.resistance\.tk$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^forums(/.*)?$ https://www.libertaire.net$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.